# UnicodeDecodeError while running Django dev server

Tags: python, django, encoding

### UnicodeDecodeError

Appears while trying to access any of the files from site media folder.

Full traceback presented in debug mode:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/site-media/img/image.png
Django Version: 1.2.3
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'special']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Languages\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Languages\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py" in serve
  59.     mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
File "C:\Languages\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py" in guess_type
  294.         init()
File "C:\Languages\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py" in init
  355.             db.read_windows_registry()
File "C:\Languages\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py" in read_windows_registry
  260.             for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
File "C:\Languages\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py" in enum_types
  250.                     ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /site-media/img/image.png
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Have you configured your urls.py file to serve static media?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a problem in Python 2.7 mimetypes.py. Look at the following discussion thread:

http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/613909b35a7462a0

There is a link to a russian article which says when google-translated:

> The presence of the standard library
>   source Python-and allowed us to find
>   the problem pretty quickly. Windows XP. I am using
>   Windows XP. 
>   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{4063BE15-3B08-470D-A0D5-B37161CFFD69}\EnableFullPage\MIME]
>   In my case the
>   problem was that in the registry under
>   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ CLSID \
>   {4063BE15-3B08-470D-A0D5-B37161CFFD69}
>   \ EnableFullPage \ MIME] contain
>   subsections containing the name of the
>   Cyrillic alphabet. If you delete these
>   keys, they are automatically
>   re-create. Therefore helped
>   to rename, just replaced the Cyrillic
>   alphabet in Latin.

Here is the article:
http://translate.google.fr/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fvictor-k-development.blogspot.com%2F2010%2F07%2Funicodedecodeerror-django.html

Comment: Sorry I'm late on approval. You was very helpful. And since I'm russian I had no trouble getting this fixed. Thanks!