# GAE: Unable to deploy app when I add a new image png into images folder

Tags: image, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm a relatively new GAE developer, and I have a successfully running app using jinja2 template framework.

I already have existing files in my /images subfolder (mainly a favicon.ico, a logo which I am already using as a static image in one of the html pages, and an iosicon.png, which I link up to the html files (using the code specified by Apple) as a default image to use when users add my webapp to their iOS homescreen.) I have no problems using these image files.

My issue: I would like to edit iosicon.png to resize it and crop it a little. I accomplished that using photoshop, and I overwrote the existing file in my local directory, without renaming it.

Now, I wish to deploy the updated app with this updated image file. However, I am unable to deploy. I receive a weird error, as quoted below.

```
2014-06-21 18:11:07 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=i.peech@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'C:\\Dropbox\\GIT\\Ambienators\\ambienators-ipeech2\\ambienators-ipeech2']"
06:11 PM Application: ambienators-ipeech2; version: 1
06:11 PM Host: appengine.google.com
06:11 PM 
Starting update of app: ambienators-ipeech2, version: 1
06:11 PM Getting current resource limits.
Password for i.peech@gmail.com: 06:11 PM Scanning files on local disk.
Could not guess mimetype for bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff.  Using application/octet-stream.
06:11 PM Cloning 17 static files.
06:11 PM Cloning 11 application files.
06:11 PM Uploading 1 files and blobs.
2014-06-21 18:11:14,457 ERROR appcfg.py:2488 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2329, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2467, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.blob_batcher.Flush()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1402, in Flush
    self.SendBatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1361, in SendBatch
    payload,
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
06:11 PM Rolling back the update.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 126, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 122, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5220, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5211, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2886, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4890, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3682, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3735, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3618, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2329, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2467, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.blob_batcher.Flush()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1402, in Flush
    self.SendBatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1361, in SendBatch
    payload,
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
2014-06-21 18:11:15 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

Just to clarify, I am 100% sure this new png file is causing the error. I have tried to restore the previous png file. The error disappears and deployment completes successfully. When I duplicate the existing png files, the deployment also completes successfully. The problem only arises when I add new png files (even if they are of identical file names as previous existing ones).

Am I doing something wrong here? Am I missing a crucial step?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: how this problem solved? anyone!!

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following two threads useful:

[UnicodeDecodeError while running Django dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214151/unicodedecodeerror-while-running-django-dev-server)

http://forum.cogsci.nl/index.php?p=/discussion/1018/solved-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc3-in-position-27-ordinal-not-in-range/p1

Comment: Tried that, but nope, same problem arises! Thanks for your help though.